# Conditionally merge pd.DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to know if this is possible with pandas:

- From `df2`, I want to create `new1` and `new2`.
- `new1` as the latest date that can find from `df1` that match column A
  and B.
- `new2` as the latest date that can find from `df1` that match column A
  but not B.
- I managed to get `new1` but not `new2`.

### Code:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = [['1/1/19', 'xy','p1','54'], ['1/1/19', 'ft','p2','20'], ['3/15/19', 'xy','p3','60'],['2/5/19', 'xy','p4','40']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1, columns = ['Name', 'A','B','C']) 

d2 =[['12/1/19', 'xy','p1','110'], ['12/10/19', 'das','p10','60'], ['12/20/19', 'fas','p50','40']]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2, columns = ['Name', 'A','B','C'])

d3 = [['12/1/19', 'xy','p1','110','1/1/19','3/15/19'], ['12/10/19', 'das','p10','60','0','0'], ['12/20/19', 'fas','p50','40','0','0']]

dfresult = pd.DataFrame(d3, columns = ['Name', 'A','B','C','new1','new2'])
```

Updated!

Comment: I can't parse what your question is. Could you provide an example in text?

Comment: Where does the `new2` date come from? It doesn't appear in `df1` nor `df2`. What's the point of the `C` column on `df1` ?

Comment: @JuanC, yea, just looked at the image (almost put in an https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) but what/from where sourced is this date?

Comment: sorry I just updated it as new2  result should ve been 3/15/19

Comment: There's a slow manual way of doing this by determining what the specific value should be for each entry inside some function and then applying that function for all entries. It's not elegant, but it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to add two columns to `df2` : `new1` and `new2`.

First I modified two things:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1, columns = ['Name1', 'A','B','C']) 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2, columns = ['Name2', 'A','B','C'])

df1.Name1 = pd.to_datetime(df1.Name1)
```

Renamed `Name` into `Name1` and `Name2` for ease of use. Then I turned `Name1` into a real date, so we can get the maximum date by group.

Then, We merge df2 with df1 on `A` column. This will give us rows that match on that column

```
aux = df2.merge(df1, on='A')
```

Then when the `B` columns is the same on both dataframes, we get `Name1` out of it:

```
df2['new1'] = df2.index.map(aux[aux.B_x==aux.B_y].Name1).fillna(0)
```

If they're different we get the maximum date for every `A` group:

```
df2['new2'] = df2.A.map(aux[aux.B_x!=aux.B_y].groupby('A').Name1.max()).fillna(0)
```

Ouput:

```
      Name2    A    B    C                 new1                 new2
0   12/1/19   xy   p1  110  2019-01-01 00:00:00  2019-03-15 00:00:00
1  12/10/19  das  p10   60                    0                    0
2  12/20/19  fas  p50   40                    0                    0
```

Comment: Thank you! 'new2' worked perfectly but for some reason, 'new1' brought me all 0's. I will research how map works exactly  (I applied this to my database)

Comment: It's weird that `new1` isn't working. Maybe with a left join instead of an inner. `map` is a very useful function, it does lot of things, but in this case it joins a column (or index) from a dataframe, with the index from another one and broadcasts that to a new column. Because I grouped by `A` for `new2`, the index of `aux[aux.B_x!=aux.B_y].groupby('A').Name1.max()` will be values from `A`  and thus I performed `df2.A.map`. It's a little hard to understand at first, but then you get used to it

Comment: You can also check if `aux[aux.B_x==aux.B_y]` is empty to see if that's why you're getting only zeroes on `new1`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by:

- standard merge based on A
- removing all entries which match B values
- sorting for dates
- dropping duplicates on A, keeping last date (n.b. assumes dates are in date format, not as strings!)
- merging back on id

Thus:

```
source = df1.copy()  # renamed
v = df2.merge(source, on='A', how='left')  # get all values where df2.A == source.A
v = v[v['B_x'] != v['B_y']]  # drop entries where B values are the same
nv = v.sort_values(by=['Name_y']).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name_x'], keep='last')
df2.merge(nv[['Name_y', 'Name_x']].rename(columns={'Name_y': 'new2', 'Name_x': 'Name'}),
          on='Name', how='left')  # keeps non-matching, consider inner
```

This yields:

```
Out[94]: 
       Name    A    B    C     new2
0   12/1/19   xy   p1  110  3/15/19
1  12/10/19  das  p10   60      NaN
2  12/20/19  fas  p50   40      NaN
```

---

My initial thought was to do something like the below. Sadly, it is not elegant. Generally, this sort of way to determining some value are frowned upon mostly because it fails to scale and with large data, gets especially slow.

```
def find_date(row, source=df1):  # renamed df1 to source
    t = source[source['B'] != row['B']]
    t = t[t['A'] == row['A']]
    return t.sort_values(by='date', ascending=False).iloc[0]

df2['new2'] = df2.apply(find_date, axis=1)
```